# Finding six consecutive integers in three lines of string

Tags: java, substring, ocr

I have written an OCR program in Java where it scans documents and finds all text in it. My primary task is to find the Invoice number which can be 6 or more integer.

I used the substring functionality but that's not so efficient as the position of that number is changing with every document, but it is always present in the first three lines of OCR text.

I want to write code in Java 8 from where I can iterate through the first three lines and get this 6 consecutive numbers.

I am using **Tesseract** for OCR.

Example:

```
,——— ————i_
g DAILYW RK SHE 278464
E C 0 mp] on THE POUJER Hello, Mumbai, Co. Maha
```

from this, I need to extract the number **278464**.

Please help!!

Comment: @Lino 6 _or more_ so it should be `(\d{6,})`

Comment: Something like this

`
String receiptNumber = "";
for (int j = 0; j<text..length(); j++) {
 receiptNumber.matches(("^(\\d{6,})$"));
}

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code using regex.

```
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)\\d{6}(?!\\d)");
    String str = "g DAILYW RK SHE 278464";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.find()){
        String s = matcher.group();
        //278464
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

- (?<=\\D) match but not catch text current and before current are not numbers
- \\d{6}  match exactly 6 numbers
- (?!\\d) match but not catch text current and after current are not numbers

Comment: Since OP is looking for 6 or more digits your regex can be simplified, no need to check for non-digits. See my comment to the question

Comment: I agree, if only I can upvote your comment but I don't have enough reputation yet. Thanks for your help Joakim Danielson.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved simply with `\\d{6,}` as shown below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Tests
        String[] textArr1 = { ",——— ————i_", "g DAILYW RK SHE 2784647",
                "E C 0 mp] on THE POUJER Hello, Mumbai, Co. Maha" };
        String[] textArr2 = { ",——— ————i_", "g DAILYW RK SHE ——— ————",
                "E C 0 mp] on THE 278464 POUJER Hello, Mumbai, Co. Maha" };
        String[] textArr3 = { ",——— 278464————i_", "g DAILYW RK SHE POUJER",
                "E C 0 mp] on THE POUJER Hello, Mumbai, Co. Maha" };
        System.out.println(getInvoiceNumber(textArr1));
        System.out.println(getInvoiceNumber(textArr2));
        System.out.println(getInvoiceNumber(textArr3));
    }

    static String getInvoiceNumber(String[] textArr) {
        String invoiceNumber = "";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6,}");
        for (String text : textArr) {    
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                invoiceNumber = matcher.group();
            }
        }
        return invoiceNumber;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2784647
278464
278464
```

Comment: One comment, compile the pattern before the loop and not inside it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Thanks for the valuable suggestion. I've updated my answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

check this code.

```
public class Test {

private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6,})");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("here put your file path"));
        System.out.println("done");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            // create matcher for pattern p and given string
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            // if an occurrence if a pattern was found in a given string...
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1)); // second matched digits
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use `try(...)` to safely close a resource. Also, you don't need to put the entire pattern in `(..)`, group zero will always contain the entire match. Further, `Scanner` is already a pattern matching tool. You are ignoring its capabilities by only using it for `nextLine()`, to apply a `Pattern` manually.  →`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{6,}"); public static void main(String[] args) { try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("your file path"))) { String match; while((match = scanner.findWithinHorizon(p, 0)) != null) { System.out.println(match); } } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { ... } }`